# Windows 8 mjpeg video decoding capabilities

Tags: windows, codec, mjpeg, decoder

Since windows 7 build-in mjpeg decoder seems has resolution limitation, it could not decode the mjpeg which has resolution larger than 2592x1944 pixels. So I want to know the ability of windows 8 decoder for mjpeg, could it decode the mjpeg video which resolution larger than 2592x1944 pixels?

Answer (score 0):

I found the build-in decoder could handle the high resolution of 2592x1944 pixels after I trying it on windows 8.